# UILocalNotification repeatInterval doesn't fire if user doesn't open app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I have an app that uses `UILocalNotification` to set a repeating notification. When the user gives the app permission, I set a notification in the `AppDelegate.m` to repeat at 9pm every night but it's not firing consistently.

As far as I can tell, it seems like the notification will fire if the user opened the app at some point during the day (i.e. after the last notification fired at 9pm yesterday and before 9pm today when the next one fires), but when they don't open the app all day, no notification arrives.

I've tried cancelling all notifications in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` before creating a new one, and *not* cancelling and recreating them. I don't know what else to try or why the OS isn't handling this for me. I noticed when using other to do list apps on my phone that often the badge count doesn't update for the day until I open the app. Is this an iOS limitation? If so, why bother using `repeatInterval` if the OS can't handle it for you unless your app gets opened anyway?

Here's the method I use for creating my notification:

```
- (void)createLocalNotification {

// Create local notification
self.localnotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
self.localnotif.alertBody = @"Time to rate your day!";
self.localnotif.alertAction = @"Rate";

// Set a date of today for the date components
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar]
                                    components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];

// Set the date components time to 9pm for notification
dateComponents.hour = 21;
dateComponents.minute = 0;

// Pass in userInfo dict
self.localnotif.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"mood rating", @"notification", nil];

NSDate *fireDate = [[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

// Set fireDate for notification and schedule it
self.localnotif.fireDate = fireDate;
self.localnotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

// Make the notification repeat every day
self.localnotif.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:self.localnotif];

}
```

I call this method from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in my `AppDelegate.m` like this:

```
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].scheduledLocalNotifications.count >= 1) {
// handle notification here
} else {
    [self createLocalNotification];
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I also tried using `NSDayCalendarUnit` etc. even though they're deprecated in iOS 8 but that didn't fix it either.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might be related in iOS 8, I think you need to register for notifications for local notifications. They will show up within the app if you haven't registered but will fail outside the app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1

Comment: Thanks Andy! I have a modal that pops up when the user first logs into the app to ask if I can notify them. When they tap "yes" I call  `[self createLocalNotification]` in my AppDelegate's `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings` method. As far as I can tell, that seems to be the right way to do it and it works since I can then send the user notifications. They just don't always arrive when they should.